# How to Sum values in a column from a list in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example,
I have a table full of data and I want to get the sum of balances with a certain account number.

BALANCES

| AcctNum | ChkNum | ChkBal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 11111 | 15.00 |
| 15 | 55555 | 3.00 |
| 10 | 22222 | 20.00 |
| 20 | 33333 | 500.00 |
| 20 | 77777 | 600.00 |
| 20 | 88888 | 700.00 |

How would I get SQL to down a list in the Where clause to do the sum per AcctNum?

I know I could go one by one doing this:

```
select sum(Amt)
from BALANCES
where AcctNum = 10
```

I tried this:

```
select sum(Amt)
from BALANCES
where AcctNum in (10, 15, 20)
```

But it combines all of the balances together.

I can't figure how to word it so that the results come out at as:

| AcctNum | ChkBal |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 35.00 |
| 15 | 3.00 |
| 20 | 1800.00 |

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`.

Comment: If you could only `select sum` of `Amt` as well as `acctNum` `from balances` table `group`ed `by AcctNum`, this would be an easy problem to solve

Comment: Thanks! I was overthinking it. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter it based on a specific account number, you can try

```
SELECT 
    AcctNum, 
    SUM(ChkBal) AS TotalChkBal
FROM 
    BALANCES
WHERE 
    AcctNum IN (10, 15, 20)
GROUP BY 
    AcctNum;
```